# Verificar consultas abertas e fechadas para incluir evento no calendário

Tags: php, mysql

Estou desenvolvendo uma agenda online e preciso verificar quando inclui um evento se existe a data e horário em consultas marcadas e abertas.

**As consultas marcadas no banco de dados estão com valor "nao".**

**As consultas abertas no banco de dados estão com valor "sim".**

Fiz esses selects no banco dados para fazer essas verificações acima, porém não tive o resultado esperado. Ele até marca as consultas que já estão no registro, mas também inclui no banco de dados o mesmo horário (quando não deveria).

Como posso resolver isso?

```
//$data_atual= date("d/m/Y");
$data_atual= $_POST['data'];

//echo $_POST['repita']."<br>";



$data = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $data_atual); // Define a data inicial
$fim = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $_POST['data_termino']); // Define a data final
$intervaloDias = $_POST['repita']; // Define o intervalo de dias

while ($data->format('Y-m-d') <= $fim->format('Y-m-d')) { // Verifica se a data é menor que a data final

$valor_start=$data->format('Y-m-d '.trim($_POST['hora_inicio']).":00".'');
$valor_end=$data->format('Y-m-d '.trim($_POST['hora_final']).":00".'');




$sql89 = "SELECT * FROM events WHERE start <='".$valor_start."' and end >='".$valor_end."' and ativo='sim'  and atendente='2'";

$result89 = $conn->query($sql89);

if ($result89->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row89 = $result89->fetch_assoc()) {

                      ?>

<div class="col-md-6 ">
<div class="borda_data_erro">
<p><b><strong>Esse dia e horário já existe em Consultas abertas</strong> </b></p>
<p><i class="m-r-10 mdi mdi-calendar-remove"></i> Início: <b><? echo $valor_start ?></b></p>
<p><i class="m-r-10 mdi mdi-calendar-remove"></i> Final: <b><? echo $valor_end ?></b></p>
</div>      
</div>

<?
    }}
$sql98 = "SELECT * FROM events WHERE start <='".$valor_start."' and end >='".$valor_end."' and ativo='nao'  and atendente='2'";

$result98 = $conn->query($sql98);

if ($result98->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row98 = $result98->fetch_assoc()) {

                      ?>

<div class="col-md-6 ">
<div class="borda_data_erro">
<p><b><strong>Esse dia e horário já existe em Consultas marcadas</strong> </b></p>
<p><i class="m-r-10 mdi mdi-calendar-remove"></i> Início: <b><? echo $valor_start ?></b></p>
<p><i class="m-r-10 mdi mdi-calendar-remove"></i> Final: <b><? echo $valor_end ?></b></p>
</div>      
</div>

<?
    }}






else{
    mysqli_query($connection,"INSERT INTO `events` (
                                            `title` ,
                                            `atendente` ,
                                            `titulo_consulta` ,
                                            `start` ,
                                            `end` ,
                                            `uid` 
                                            )
                                            VALUES (
                                            '".$_POST["title"]." - ".$nomeUsuario."',
                                            '".mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,"$idusuario")."',
                                            '".mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST["title"])."',
                                            '$valor_start',
                                            '$valor_end',
                                            '".mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$uid)."'
                                            )");
                                            $sql = "SELECT * FROM events order by id DESC LIMIT 0,1";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        //echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - Name: " . $row["firstname"]. " " . $row["lastname"]. "<br>";

        $id_evento= $row["id"];
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}


mysqli_query($connection,"INSERT INTO `valor_consulta` (`id_evento` , `valor`)
                       VALUES (
                       '".mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$id_evento)."',
                       '".mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST["valor_cosulta"])."'
                       )");



                                ?>
                      <div class="col-md-6">
<div class="borda_data">
<p><b>Consulta em aberto cadastrada2</b></p>
<p><i class="m-r-10 mdi mdi-calendar-check"></i> Início: <b><? echo $valor_start ?></b></p>
<p><i class="m-r-10 mdi mdi-calendar-check"></i> Final: <b><? echo $valor_end ?></b></p>
</div>
</div>

                      <?
}                         
                        $data = $data->add(new DateInterval('P'.$intervaloDias.'D')); // Incrementa a data

                                //echo $data->format('Y-m-d ') . "\n"; // Escreve a data na tela





                            }
```